# YouTube api audio doesn't stop playing

Tags: flash, audio, actionscript-2, youtube-api

OK I have built an application which uses the youtube API. It loads a video into the application when the user clicks a button. If the user clicks another button a new video is loaded in it's place. You can see it here: http://www.grantanderson.net/blogFiles/honours/youtube.html

Everything works except the audio from the previous video doesn't stop.

I use

```
ytplayer.stopVideo();

ytplayer.clearVideo();
```

I tried adding at the end of this

```
ytplayer.destroy();
```

But it hasn't fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With AS2, you often have memory issues.  Unfortunately this is often unavoidable.  The good news is that there is a way around that.

```
ytplayer.swapDepths( 1000 );
delete ytplayer;

createEmptyMovieClip( "whoCares", 1000 );
delete whoCares;
```

It is a bit... overkill, but this will destroy any display object completely.